# Close table caption in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I use huxtable in bookdown. How can I close the table caption in bookdown?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8pu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set

```r
options(huxtable.bookdown = FALSE)
```

and you shouldn't see the autogenerated captions.

Comment: Is there a specific place where you look for such resources? Or to put it differently: How did you come up with this solution?

Comment: I'm the package author.  `help("huxtable-options")` would have given you a hint. So would `?label`. Perhaps it should be mentioned in `?caption` too.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about hiding the caption you can use css to adjust its color to whatever background color you have set. In your case "white". Note: The caption is still there but you can't see it.

```yaml
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---
```

````
```{css}
caption {
  color: white;
}
```
````

````
```{r}
huxtable::hux(mtcars)
```
````